# Laravel 4: copy from local to live server

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to copy a project from localhost to live server done in Laravel 4 framework.
On the local machine it is working, but I have this error in live server:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
/**********/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 
/**********/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

I didn't modify those files.

Thanks

Comment: What's your server's php version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line `46` there is

```
Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup::initAll();
```

and `php` complaining for `\` which means it doesn't supprt `namespace`, you have to upgrade to `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0` because right now it's (on your live server) prior to `PHP 5.3.0` and remember that `laravel` requires `PHP >= 5.3.7` so upgrade your `php` version.